# How to share my web app to different users

Tags: web-applications, server, hosting, multi-tenant

I hosted my web app on a server. 
The web app is composed of a client part (which will only see users) and an administrative part (which will only see the owner of the restaurant). 
Let's assume that the www.food1.com and www.food2.com restaurant want to buy my app.
Is there a way to avoid installing my app on their servers?
I would like my app to be installed only on my server and based on who to access my app (www.food1.com or www.food2.com), access the food1 or food2 database.

If I buy a host, can I create various domains in order to distinguish the various customers?

So the problem is not to host my code on a server that others will buy.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question, you will have to evaluate many factors to decide on the approach, you seem to be having a requirement for a Multi-Tenant application, you can go through the various levels of multi-tenancy.

The option that you can choose is to have a single code base with databases per tenant like (Food1 -> Food1DB, Food2 -> Food2DB), the tenant identification strategy can be to use different domains, preferable to use a subdomain like food2.yourcompany.com, food1.yourcompany.com.

Few factors to guide you to choosing the strategy

1. Level of data uniqueness per tenant and the data volume expected
2. Are they going to be geographically distributed
3. What levels of customizations in your application, the end customers will prefer to

and lots more. Please think through and come up with a specific problem that we can tackle.